# Java Image Compression : colour changes

Tags: java, image-processing

I am using below code for reducing image size. It reduces size from 1MB to 250 KB. Its fine but it changes image colour.

```
File input = new File("ImageTOCompress.jpg");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);

File compressedImageFile = new File("CompressedImage.jpg");
OutputStream os =new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);

Iterator<ImageWriter>writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();

ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
writer.setOutput(ios);

ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionQuality(0.05f);
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);

os.close();
ios.close();
writer.dispose();
```

Please help me to maintain image colour as it is...Thanks!!!

Comment: In what way does it change it?

Comment: First I have to ask, do you understand the difference between "lossy" and "lossless" compression?  Do you understand what the effect of calling  "setCompressionQuality(0.05f)" has on your image quality? More specifically, have you tried other values?

Comment: Solved..actually it was my mistake to verify the input file...that file was actully tiff and I was considering it as a jpg format..thats why the above prog did not work. Thanks Dainel.